# One assertion for all tests in jMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a large test plan with more than 200 tests but there is one thing in common, the API I'm calling for my tests should always return a JSON encoded response. 
I'm using ATLANTBH JSON assertion that I can put after each and every test, but is there a way to put an assertion which should be validated for all tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it as a child of Thread Group, it will be applied to all requests.

Read:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules